# Anonymous access for links to documents but nothing else

Tags: 2010, permissions

I've done a ton of searching and couldn't find any potential solutions to my problem so hopefully someone has an idea.

First off, this is SP 2010 Foundation.

Currently, our site requires authentication and anonymous authentication is not enabled.  What I'd like to do is have links to sharepoint documents in a different, publicly accessible application.  They would need to be able to open these links to view the document, but I do not want them to be able to view anything else in SP at all.  If I give anonymous access to the library then they'd be able to browse that library, not just the links I give them.  Individual item permissions isn't an option since I may be dealing with 1000's of documents.

I think what I may be asking for is a way to allow anonymous access on a library, but not on views?   Is this possible?  Is there some other way of achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is completely different than what you may have in mind, but I would create an event receiver that would capture any edits/additions, and then copy them to a separate anonymous site. That way the content between each site will be segregated and no funny business would be allowed.

You could also just create a PowerShell script that runs once a day, that would copy newly modified documents to the other site. I think this is reasonable as anonymity is more important here than documents being fresh.

Edit: Based on your requirement, you could use the Document ID service, which you can facilitate the links on your side but essentially the Document ID service works with the Search Service in order to generate an ID for each document. This can be traced to the document itself without have a URL that allows them to tell where the document came from. It comes in the url form like this: `http://sharepoint/sites/sitecollection/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=MADNJJ5YU327-1-5` which you can use to send to whoever needs to look at it.

Comment: This is something I may do but part of the issue is that I would like to prevent the anonymous users from being able to browse the library.  If given a link, they could trim it and view the whole library on the subsite.

Comment: how are you determining which "anonymous" user gets rights to which file? Are you emailing the link?

Comment: I have a couple different uses in mind, one of which is emailing a link, yes.  i realize everyone will technically be able to access all the docs but I just don't want them to freely be able to browse all of them.  The other potential use is a web mapping application that links a feature to a corresponding plan.  Again, i just want the link to work for anyone but not let them peruse the entire library at will.  It's not that the rest of the docs need to be locked down per se, just that there's a process in place for seeing them.

Comment: can you elaborate on your process so I can get a better idea on what kind of use this is for--and be able to determine a good approach? If users don't need to be locked down, you should be able to send them a link to the document, only tech saavy users would know to strip out the url to find the library. How often are users sent links to these documents? Could you break down the access based on roles? Then you could create webpart pages that show a group of documents...

Comment: I mean that there is a process for seeing the rest of the documents in the library (Right To Know).  It's difficult to know who does and doesn't know how to strip the url....but worth considering.  We are still in the brainstorming stage so hard to say how often it'll be used but links may only be sent like once a week....the mapping application would be used constantly though.  I do not want roles because that would require a login.  I'm not sure what else to elaborate on...this is as far as I'm into the planning.

Comment: Ok, See my edit.

Comment: Document ID would be useful I suspect but it is not available in Sharepoint Foundation.  (yet another reason why I should probably upgrade)